# How to change the position of the skeleton in all frames with a script?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

There is animation. For example 40 frames. It is required using a script to change the position of the skeleton along the Z axis in all frames. For example, raise the skeleton in all frames by + 2 along the Z axis. Please tell me how to do this or where can I read about it?
Regards. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make an Empty.

Make the Empty a parent to the skeleton.

Move the Empty to where needed, the skeleton will move with it.

Comment: Thank you! A good idea. But exporting to BVH in the game engine does not change anything. The animation position is above the ground. The character is in the air. It doesn't stand on the ground.